# My Windows 8.1 windows key is "stuck" (not physically)

Tags: windows, windows-8

I recently purchased an MSI ge40 laptop.

It's been running fine (very hot laptop though) except for one issue. When I use windows key + L to lock the laptop, upon typing in my password and logging in, pressing any key that would normally be used in combination with the windows key activates that program.

So, if I hit win+L, type password, then hit 's' the search comes up. Etc.

This also randomly seems to happen when I am not using win+L. I might just be browsing the web and then I hit 's' when I am typing a url and then boom, search pops up. Very annoying.

I fix this by hitting the win key....sometimes onces, sometimes 10 times. Doesn't seem to have to do with the hardness of the strike.

I guess I'm at a loss. I researched this and only results about vista and 7 come up.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue, try using a different keyboard for a day to rule it out.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to another keyboard :(

Comment: This might kill you but you should have access to a on-screen keyboard, If it's not sticking there it's hardware.

Comment: Are all of your drivers/firmware/bios up to date?

Comment: This sounds like a detective product

Comment: Well, the on screen keyboard works fine.

Comment: @Ramhound Shouldn't be hard to sleuth out the cause, then.

Comment: @AaronMiller Yep contact the OEM and request either an updated driver or a replacement unit because it's either hardware or the driver

Comment: If you recently purchased said computer, and you are having heat issues already, and your keyboard is acting up, then I would be very wary of using it, and would be contacting the manufacturer. Heat is bad for computers and excess heat is certainly going to be bad in the long run. You are best to get it resolved NOW, rather then later when you really have issues, and it isn't covered by warranty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact same problem on Windows 8.1.  I found and fixed the problem.  If you have "Start Menu 8" installed, download the latest version.  v1.4 has better support for Windows 8.1 and fixes the "Win Key Cannot Be Released" bug.

Comment: I had this same exact problem, and updating to 1.4 fixed it.  Running 8.0, not 8.1 here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, drove me crazy for weeks, finally figure out it was an app I had installed to replace the Windows 8 start menu called "Classic Start", after uninstall it all was well again. I would have assume this was the same issue people were having with start menu 8 app. I haven't tried install the latest version of either, thanks.