# Windows Key seems to be stuck (not physically)

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, hotkeys, windows-key

Good morning everybody! I've seen similar threads but none solved my issue.

My Asus EEEPC 1015PE has Windows 8.1 installed and it's going on and off on an issue that the Windows Key will be stuck. It's not stuck physically, as I try pressing it and it won't go to Metro. I removed the key and sprayed a contact cleaner, it still wouldn't unstick.

I looked into the post [My Windows 8.1 windows key is "stuck" (not physically)](https://superuser.com/questions/675153/my-windows-8-1-windows-key-is-stuck-not-physically) and tried uninstalling the keyboard driver as it was suggested, uninstalling Windows 8 Start Menu (Classic Shell, Start Menu 8, WinAeroCharmsBarKiller and whatnot) programs and even tried as a last resort to remove the Windows Hotkeys via Regedit with the following methods:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer] "NoWinKeys"=dword:00000001

http://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/disable-windows-key
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,5B,E0,00,00,00,00

Tried Microsoft's KB216893, but this one wouldn't do the trick as it's not for Windows 8/8.1

I have also tried disabling some functions from Ease of Access to no success.

Not even the last method worked fully, as even though it stopped going to Search when I pressed "S" and stopped going to Run when I pressed "R", it will still Logout when I press "L" and malfunction with other keys. Even with the On-Screen Keyboard if I press "L" it will logout.

I remember having flashed a portable OS to rule any Windows 8.1 software issue out, and it seemed the key was still stuck, although I didn't test it this time I believe if I try it it will still be an issue.

So, what should I do? Is changing the keyboard my only option? Thanks!

Comment: As I stated in the first line, I had seen other threads not only in Superuser. The thread in specific I made my title as close as possible as it's the same issue but without any solution yet.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. **Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs**. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Everything I said I did I took from somewhere in the internet. I will edit my post and give links if that's the case.